# How to close an Android app using UiAutomator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

How can I close an especific Android app using UiAutomator API? 
Like when you manually press the Recents button and swipe the app you want to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option would be to use getUiDevice.pressRecentApps, this will load up the recent apps for you, then take a screenshot using the uiautomator viewerso you have a view of the xml of the screen that has been loaded. You can then use this xml to select the object you wish to swipe using

```
UiObject app = new UIObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("The id of the app");
app.swipeLeft(100);
```

or right

This should be able to close your app. The xml will depend on what style of android you are using and the device.

Comment: This won't shut the app completely, e.g. services with sticky notifications will still be visible. And (if the notifications contain animated elements like progress bars) fail following Espresso tests out of the blue sky

Comment: ... or up (Pixel)

Comment: How do you determine the String to pass to resourceId()?

Answer (score 8):

Better way (not device, OS version, UI or orientation specific):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"am", "force-stop", "pkg.name.of.your.app"});
```

Tested and working on a Nexus 5X with android 6.0

Comment: Important: notice that this is not exactly like swiping the app off recent apps. This command will stop all background services\listeners\etc. that the app has started, while swiping the app away will only clear its activities.

Comment: ``java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from pid=6611, uid=10231 requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES`` But this permission is reserved for system apps only

Comment: Did you get that error running the line of code inside an App or inside a UIAutomator process? Because UIAutomator should count as a system app I belive

Comment: I added an extra after statement to my test running with ``AndroidJUnit4.class`` : ``@After public void stopApp() { Runtime.getRuntime().... } ``

Comment: I'm not familiar with AndroidJUnit4, but I would guess that it runs as an app on the device (if it even runs on a physical device?). I would also reconsider trying to forcefully close apps inside a unit test...

Comment: `device.executeShellCommand("am force-stop $PACKAGE_NAME")`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I kill all android apps at once with uiautomator:

```
public static void killApps()
{
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    try
    {
        device.pressHome();
        device.pressRecentApps();

        // Clear all isn't always visible unless you scroll all apps down
        int height = device.getDisplayHeight();
        int width = device.getDisplayWidth();
        device.swipe(width/2,height/2, width/2, height, 50);

        UiObject clear = device.findObject(new UiSelector()
            .resourceId("com.android.systemui:id/button")
            .text("CLEAR ALL")
        );
        if (clear.exists())
        {
            clear.click();
        }
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: As @PhilLab said in other answers, swiping away is not the same as force-quitting

Answer (score 0):

Building on the solution from @user597159 I got the following to close all applications on a Pixel 2 for Firebase Test Lab (i.e. the "walleye" device type):

```
private void killAllApps() throws Exception {
    boolean keepSwiping = true;
    int maxSwipeAttempts = 10;
    uiDevice.pressRecentApps();

    for (int swipeAttempt=0; swipeAttempt<maxSwipeAttempts && keepSwiping; swipeAttempt++) {
        int height = uiDevice.getDisplayHeight();
        int width = uiDevice.getDisplayWidth();
        uiDevice.swipe(width / 2, height / 2, width, height / 2, 50);

        UiObject clearAll1 = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Clear all"));
        UiObject clearAll2 = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textStartsWith("Clear all"));
        UiObject clearAll3 = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("Clear all"));
        UiObject clear = clearAll1.exists() ? clearAll1 :
                (clearAll2.exists() ? clearAll2 : clearAll3);

        if (clear.exists()) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Attempting to close app by killAllApps and found clear=all button on swipeAttempt=" + swipeAttempt);
            clear.click();
            keepSwiping = false;
        } else {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "Attempting to close app by killAllApps but have to keep swiping swipeAttempt=" + swipeAttempt);
            keepSwiping = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note on the Pixel 2, it is spelled "Clear all" not "CLEAR ALL".

I could not get some of the other solutions to work.  I got `UiObjectNotFoundException` for the following:

```
app = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("SDK Test App"));
```

And also for:

```
app = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().className(com.locuslabs.android.sdk.SdkTestApplication.class));
```

In other words `app.exists()` returned false for these approaches that attempted to swipe up on the app to close on Pixel 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Kotlin answer that is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55877053/5163090). It adds an extension function to UiDevice to clear all tasks. I tested this on a Pixel 2 emulator.

```
fun UiDevice.clearAllTasks(swipeAttempts: Int = 10 ) {
    pressRecentApps()

    var currentAttempt = 1
    val centerScreenX = displayWidth / 2
    val centerScreenY = displayHeight / 2
    while (currentAttempt <= swipeAttempts) {
        Timber.d("Clear all tasks attempt $currentAttempt")
        swipe(centerScreenX, centerScreenY, displayWidth, centerScreenY, 50)
        val uiObject = findObject(UiSelector().text("Clear all"))
        if (uiObject.exists()) {
            uiObject.click()
            break
        } else {
            currentAttempt++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't work in landscape ?